# parametrising sql query

Tags: php, sql

I have the following function that I am trying to secure from SQL injection but I keep getting errors, any ideas?

```
function get_main_info($application_id){

    if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
    $conn = create_connection();
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $query = "SELECT * from application  where id = :application_id and created_by= :user_id";
    var_dump($application_id);die();

    $row = $conn->query($query)->fetch();
    $row->bindValue(':application_id', $application_id);
    $row->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id);
    return $row;
}
```

Comment: What errors? The misplaced space in `: user_id` might have something to do with it.

Comment: fixed that but that's not the problem, I get a  Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Comment: Oh well yeah, you're running the query as-is, you're not calling `prepare` at all.

Comment: function get_main_info($application_id){
 
 if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
 $conn = create_connection();
 $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
 $query = "SELECT * from application  where id = :application_id and created_by= :user_id";
    //var_dump($application_id);die();
 
    $row = $conn->prepare($query)->fetch();
    $row->bindValue(':application_id', $application_id);
 $row->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id);
    $row->execute();
 return $row;
}

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindValue() on boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Check if the following makes sense to resolve your issue:

```
function get_main_info($application_id){

    if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

    $conn = create_connection();
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

    /*
    $query = "SELECT * from application  where id = :application_id and created_by= :user_id";
    var_dump($application_id);die();

    $row = $conn->query($query)->fetch();
    $row->bindValue(':application_id', $application_id);
    $row->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id);
    */

    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * from application  where id = :application_id and created_by= :user_id");
    $query->bindValue(':application_id', $application_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $row = $query->fetchAll();

    return $row;

}
```